# Connect WinSCP or other FTP GUI tools to Vagrant box

Tags: ftp, vagrant, winscp

Is it possible to connect WinSCP or other FTP based GUI tools like FileZilla etc.. to Vagrant box managed Ubuntu instance?

Currently I have Ubuntu 14.04 running on Windows host (using VirtualBox). I just want WinSCP to connect to this running guest OS so that I can view/edit files in a more user friendly way.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as long as you have FTP server running on the Ubuntu instance and the client and the server can talk over the network then this is possible.

This would be no different than setup on an environment that is not virtualized so as long as the network can communicate between the two and you have the server configured properly.

Once you have the setup complete you can connect from WinSCP on Windows to the FTP server on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use winscp to login to vagrant box. You need to use localhost as hostname and port number = 2222.